# Localized String not loading from customised bundle in M1 chip machine

Tags: swift, security, bundle, apple-m1

We have a customized authorization bundle, registered for access to the resources.
Localized string not loading with M1 chip machine. But it works fine in Intel-based machines.

The bundle contains localized.strings for all supported languages

Any idea what could be the issue?

We have checked the preferred languages also return properly. Locale.current returns "En" always

Comment: Did you remember to check the target membership for each localized file?

Comment: Yes, we have selected the target membership, Bundle has a respective .lproj folder

Answer (score 0):

We found the root cause. that it's not picking from the respective resources file.
We have done a workaround that based on the language we are constructing the bundle path with the respective language resource file. So that it reads required localized strings.